# Fast lexing during edit-time

Tags: parsing, compilation, compiler-construction, language-agnostic

I'm wondering what techniques are employed to fast lex a huge source file (e.g. C++) in popular text editors.

Re-lexing an entire document each time I edit the file (i.e. I add some characters) could quickly become unfeasible.. but those characters might change everything (towards the top, towards the bottom or both) into the source file, as it is the case when inserting

```
/*
```

or

```
\*
```

halfway through the huge file.

Is there a standard approach to runtime lexing?

Comment: Lexing is extremely fast. Do you mean *paraing?*

Comment: @EJP: Do you mean *parsing*?

Comment: How could nserting some characters change the lex *towards the top*? (At least, more than the current token, which might become or stop being a keyword)

Comment: @rici If editors handled tokens exactly like compilers,  a /* without a */ would be an invalid token. If you then later inserted a */ at the bottom of the file, everything between the /* and */ would become a comment token. Of course if you enter `/*` into a text editor, you want the text to turn green even before you enter a `*/`, so a text editor's lexer shouldn't work exactly like a compiler's.

Comment: @sepp2k: yes to your second sentence. As to the first, the lexers I have written treat the text from /* to the end of the program as an unterminated comment (which is certainly an invalid token, but of a particular variety, like an unterminated string). I do this partly to avoid indefinite lexer backtracking, and partly because parse recovery in the face of an unterminated comment/string is too speculative to attempt to bother with (imo). But the key is your second observation: a text editor which coloured strings and comments bright red until they were terminated would be really annoying...

Comment: @sepp2k: ... to which it might be added that the common strategy of having the IDE insert the terminating quote or comment end marker to the right-hand side of the cursor in order to preserve the validity of the string/comment token is only slightly less annoying, at least for me.

Answer (score 2):

I'd assume the same techniques that are used to lex source files by compilers.

A good FSA-based lexer (or a hand-written one) spends only a few instructions per character. Assume a klunky machine that takes 5 nS to execute an instruction (way slow WRT modern workstations). If you have a million-character buffer (that's about 300,000 lines of 30 characters), and it takes 10 instructions to process each, the total lexing time is 50 million nS = .05 second.

Why do you think this is a problem?